Page numbering does not work
It seems like I have a problem at my page numbering. I used tikz to format the style of my sections and I made a new command for page numbering, also with tikz. The table of contents shows the page number correct, but each section shows page number in the footer just for the first page of the section. So, if i have 2-3 pages written in a section, the rest of the pages won't show the pagenumber. I also tryed to obtain the same output with fancyfoot whitout having to call out for \Footer manually, but still does not work. Than my \part always show page number no matter of what rule i give. Im out of ideas. I tryed everything, even other small scripts from this forum and nothing works. Can someone please help me fix the pagenumbers and still have the customization with tikz?
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[tmargin=2cm,rmargin=2.8cm,lmargin=2.3cm,bmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Format section titles
\titleformat{\section}[display] 
{\bfseries\color{col1}}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \fill[black, rounded corners=10] (0,0.9)--(-1.4,0)--(0,-0.8)--cycle;
        \fill[,rounded corners=10,col1!80,xshift=-0.5mm,yshift=-1mm](0,0.9)--(-1.4,0)--(0,-0.8)--cycle;
        \path[fill=black, draw=black!10, thick, xshift=-0.5mm, yshift=-0.5mm] (0,0) circle(0.5cm);
        \path[fill=white,draw=black!10,thick](0,0)circle(0.5cm)node[color=black](num){\thesection};
        \node[color=black,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=15cm,text width=10cm,align=left] (tit)at([xshift=7cm]num)[align=left,scale=1.2]{#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}{-25pt}{\bfseries\large}  % Add this line to include a horizontal line

\pagestyle{fancy} % Use fancyhdr package for headers and footers
\fancyhf{} % Clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{} % Clear center footer (remove the page number)

% Ensure that all pages use the empty style
\renewcommand{\thepage}{} % Remove page numbering
\pagenumbering{gobble} % Completely suppress page numbers

% FOOTER COMMAND %
\newcommand\Footer{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        % Check if the current page number is odd or even
        \ifodd\thepage
        % Odd page (right side)
        \node[anchor=south east, inner sep=20pt, outer sep=10pt] at (current page.south east) {
            \colorbox{col1}{\parbox[0.5cm][0.5cm][c]{2.5cm}{\centering\textcolor{white}{{\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}}}} % Right footer for odd page
        };
        \else
        % Even page (left side)
        \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=20pt, outer sep=10pt] at (current page.south west) {
            \colorbox{col1}{\parbox[0.5cm][0.5cm][c]{2.5cm}{\centering\textcolor{white}{{\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}}}} % Left footer for even page
        };
        \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

%define new colors for our pagestyle%
\definecolor{col1}{RGB}{243,111,36}
\definecolor{col2}{RGB}{0,182,187}
\definecolor{col3}{RGB}{240,225,225}
\definecolor{col4}{RGB}{221,10,138}
\definecolor{col5}{RGB}{0,182,189}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{
    \clearpage % Start TOC on a new page without forcing an odd page
    \thispagestyle{empty} % No page number on TOC page
    \clearpage % Ensure the next content starts on a new page
}

%define style for table of contents
\titlecontents{chapter}[3.8pc]
{\addvspace{30pt}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
        \draw[fill=col1,draw=col1] (-100,-.11) rectangle (-0.1,.6);%
        \pgftext[left,x=-3.5cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large\sc\bfseries Capitolul\ \thecontentslabel};%
    \end{tikzpicture}\color{col1}\large\sc\bfseries}%
{}
{}
{\;\titlerule\;\large\sc\bfseries Pagina \thecontentspage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=col1!25,draw=col1!20] (2pt,0) rectangle (4,0.1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\titlecontents{section}[2.4pc]
    {\addvspace{1pt}}
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
    {}
    {\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
    []
\titlecontents{subsection}[4.5pc] 
    {\addvspace{1pt}}
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
    {}
    {\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
    []
\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
    \chapter*{%
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
            \pgftext[right,x=25cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\sc\bfseries \contentsname};%
            \draw[fill=col2,draw=col2] (10,-.75) rectangle (40,1);%
            \pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\sc\bfseries \contentsname};%
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \pagestyle{empty} % Hide default page numbers
    \frontmatter %non arabic numbers for pages

    %TABLE OF CONTENTS
    \tableofcontents

    \mainmatter   %arabic numbers to pages

    %FIRST PART
    \part{Recapitularea  materiei din clasele IX-X}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    

    %FIRST CHAPTER OF THE BOOK
    \chapter{Operații cu numere reale}
    \thispagestyle{empty} 
    
    \section{section1}
     \Footer
    \lipsum[10-50]
    \section{section2}
    \Footer
    \lipsum[10-30]

    \chapter{Functii}
    \Footer
    \thispagestyle{empty} % Suppress page number on this page
    
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE.

If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every post, even in the original one. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

I am really sorry... i saw on other post someone said to post it here on tex. I did not know this since i am a new user.

\renewcommand{\thepage}{} % Remove page numbering doesn't remove the page numbering from the footer, it breaks all page handling in latex. don't do that.

for example you yourself have \ifodd\thepage but \thepage is empty so this is \ifodd \node which can not end well as \node is not a number.

Posting on multiple sites is ok, but you should also include a link saying "I've also posted this (here)," so that people who find the unsolved version can also find all related versions.

(1) The code can be simplified by defining a page style that uses the \Footer command to insert the custom page number.
(2) In the book class the first page of \part is generated with the plain style. It can be patched  to replace \thispagestyle{plain} by \thispagestyle{empty}. The same approach can be applied to \chapter if so desired.

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[tmargin=2cm,rmargin=2.8cm,lmargin=2.3cm,bmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%********************************************* added    
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\part}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{} % Suppress page number on this page
%\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{} % Optional suppress page number on this page

%main footer
\fancypagestyle{main}{%
    \fancyhf{} % Clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot{\Footer}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
%*********************************************************

% Format section titles
\titleformat{\section}[display] 
{\bfseries\color{col1}}
{%
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \fill[black, rounded corners=10] (0,0.9)--(-1.4,0)--(0,-0.8)--cycle;
        \fill[,rounded corners=10,col1!80,xshift=-0.5mm,yshift=-1mm](0,0.9)--(-1.4,0)--(0,-0.8)--cycle;
        \path[fill=black, draw=black!10, thick, xshift=-0.5mm, yshift=-0.5mm] (0,0) circle(0.5cm);
        \path[fill=white,draw=black!10,thick](0,0)circle(0.5cm)node[color=black](num){\thesection};
        \node[color=black,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=15cm,text width=10cm,align=left] (tit)at([xshift=7cm]num)[align=left,scale=1.2]{#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}{-25pt}{\bfseries\large}  % Add this line to include a horizontal line


% FOOTER COMMAND %
\newcommand\Footer{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        % Check if the current page number is odd or even
        \ifodd\thepage
        % Odd page (right side)
        \node[anchor=south east, inner sep=20pt, outer sep=10pt] at (current page.south east) {
            \colorbox{col1}{\parbox[0.5cm][0.5cm][c]{2.5cm}{\centering\textcolor{white}{{\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}}}} % Right footer for odd page
        };
        \else
        % Even page (left side)
        \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=20pt, outer sep=10pt] at (current page.south west) {
            \colorbox{col1}{\parbox[0.5cm][0.5cm][c]{2.5cm}{\centering\textcolor{white}{{\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}}}} % Left footer for even page
        };
        \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

%define new colors for our pagestyle%
\definecolor{col1}{RGB}{243,111,36}
\definecolor{col2}{RGB}{0,182,187}
\definecolor{col3}{RGB}{240,225,225}
\definecolor{col4}{RGB}{221,10,138}
\definecolor{col5}{RGB}{0,182,189}

\makeatletter
%define style for table of contents
\titlecontents{chapter}[3.8pc]
{\addvspace{30pt}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
        \draw[fill=col1,draw=col1] (-100,-.11) rectangle (-0.1,.6);%
        \pgftext[left,x=-3.5cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large\sc\bfseries Capitolul\ \thecontentslabel};%
    \end{tikzpicture}\color{col1}\large\sc\bfseries}%
{}
{}
{\;\titlerule\;\large\sc\bfseries Pagina \thecontentspage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=col1!25,draw=col1!20] (2pt,0) rectangle (4,0.1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\titlecontents{section}[2.4pc]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
[]
\titlecontents{subsection}[4.5pc] 
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
[]

\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
    \chapter*{%
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
            \pgftext[right,x=25cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\sc\bfseries \contentsname};%
            \draw[fill=col2,draw=col2] (10,-.75) rectangle (40,1);%
            \pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\sc\bfseries \contentsname};%
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter %non arabic numbers for pages
    
    %TABLE OF CONTENTS
    \pagestyle{empty} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \tableofcontents
    
    \mainmatter   %arabic numbers to pages
    
    %FIRST PART
    \part{Recapitularea  materiei din clasele IX-X} 
    
    %FIRST CHAPTER OF THE BOOK
    \pagestyle{main} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \chapter{Operații cu numere reale}      
    \thispagestyle{main} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \section{section1}

    \lipsum[10-50]
    \section{section2}
    \lipsum[10-30]
    
    \chapter{Functii}
    \thispagestyle{main}
    
    \section{section3}
    \lipsum[10-30]
    
\end{document}

The code can be simplified even further by inserting a simple tikzpicture into the page  style definition.
%main footer
\fancypagestyle{main}{%
    \fancyhf{} % Clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \node {\colorbox{col1}{\parbox[0.5cm][0.5cm][c]{2.5cm}{\centering\textcolor{white}{{\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}}}}};% Right /Left footer 
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
%*********************************************************


Thank you so much. it seems like is working now by deleting the footer command and inserting the tikzpicture in the fancy foot
